# Send data from One application to other in different devices continously?

Tags: android

Hello i am new in android, I have one application which generates latitude and longitude. Now i want take it a step ahead. I want to send these lat and long continously to my other application which is installed in other android phone. Like 
APP 1 : This gets the latitude and longitude of its device continously. Now i want to tansfer these latitude and longitude to other app (APP 2).

APP 2 : This will recieve the latitude and longitude from app one and plot in map. 
The main concern is how to send data from APP1 to APP2???? Is there any examples or a way to do so? Any suggestions will be appriciated thanx in advance.

Comment: can you use middle server for getting info from App1 and send it to App2 ?

Comment: Actually i wanted them to communicate directly? Because this wont consume my server data based. All i want is real time data.. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

You can send message from one device to other by GCM
http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142

Comment: Is it chargable? Is there any other way we can do so?? Both app will be created from my side?

Comment: this is the best, simplest and efficient way to do. and it is not chargable.

Answer (score 0):

In case the two smartphones are connected to the same network, I would suggest to use Alljoyn https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation

In Alljoyn you can you can establish bidirectional communication between two devices and send/receiver whatever data you want. The example that best fits your scenario is the Chat example, you can find it here: https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat